# Make a GitHub-like file finder using Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene, query-parser

I have to make a file finder using Lucene. I thought of using wild card query.

Text in a document: `lucene/queryparser/docs/xml/img/plus.gif`

Search string: `lqdocspg`

It should find:
**l**ucene/**q**ueryparser/**docs**/xml/img/**p**lus.**g**if
(it is the olny document for now, so it should return that it found 1 match.)

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    Path indexPath = Files.createTempDirectory("tempIndex");
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexPath);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
    Document doc = new Document();
    String text = "lucene/queryparser/docs/xml/img/plus.gif";
    doc.add(new Field("fieldname", text, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
    iwriter.addDocument(doc);
    iwriter.close();

    // Now search the index:
    DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
    // Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
    //QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("fieldname", analyzer);
    //Query query = parser.parse("l*q*d*o*c*s*p*g*");
    Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("fieldname", "*l"));
    ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, 10).scoreDocs;
    System.out.println(isearcher.doc(0).get("fieldname"));
    System.out.println("Search terms found in :: " + hits.length + " files");
    assertEquals(1, hits.length);



    // Iterate through the results:
    for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) {
        Document hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hit.doc);
        assertEquals("lucene/queryparser/docs/xml/img/plus.gif", hitDoc.get("fieldname"));
    }
    ireader.close();
    directory.close();
    IOUtils.rm(indexPath);
}
```

When i am passing `*l` or `l*` or `lucene* *lucene` or any different like `q*` it's working and returns that it found match in one file.
But when im trying to pass what i want to find which is `*l*q*d*o*c*s*p*g*` it returns 0 found matches. I dont know what am i doing wrong. Asterisk means that between letters there can be anything right?

Comment: "_new to lucene and dont know where to start_" - I would start by reviewing the [official Lucene demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/demo/index.html). If you have a specific problem with a specific part of your code, you can share that as a [mre].

Comment: (Also, separately, (a) it's not clear to me why the search string `l/id//gif` would be expected to find `lucene/index/docs/img/join.gif`; and (b) GitHub has a sophisticated set of [search options](https://github.com/search/advanced). Are you saying you want to create something that does all of that?)

Comment: @andrewJames I edited my post. Could You look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are using a `TextField`:

```java
doc.add(new Field("fieldname", text, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
```

This field, when used with the standard analyzer, causes the contents of that field to be tokenized into the following separate tokens in the Lucene index (in alphabetic order):

Input value: `lucene/queryparser/docs/xml/img/plus.gif`

Resulting indexed tokens:

- `docs`
- `img`
- `lucene`
- `plus.gif`
- `queryparser`
- `xml`

Now, when you consider your wildcard query `l*q*d*o*c*s*p*g*`, you can see that this single query term does not match any of the tokens in the index.

But a query such as `l*` matches one token: `lucene` - so that will find your one and only document.

---

There are various ways to solve this - but in your specific case, given you want to treat `lucene/queryparser/docs/xml/img/plus.gif` as a single string, then you can use a `StringField` instead of a `TextField`. This class does not split the input into tokens. Instead it indexes the input without applying the Standard Analyzer.

```java
doc.add(new StringField(FIELD_NAME, documentBody, Field.Store.YES));
```

This generates a single token in the index:

- `lucene/queryparser/docs/xml/img/plus.gif`

Now you can see that your wildcard query `l*q*d*o*c*s*p*g*` should (and does) match that token.

---

See the following:

- [`Field`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) - specifically, take a look at the list of subclasses. These are "predefined" fields you can use without needing to use `new Field(...)`- like my `new StringField(...)` example above.
- [`TextField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) - "*A field that is indexed and tokenized, without term vectors. For example this would be used on a 'body' field, that contains the bulk of a document's text.*"
- [`StringField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) - "*A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token.*"